# Gradle sync failed ошибка сборки

Tags: java, gradle

Пытаюсь начать разбираться с JUnit тестированием. Собираюсь использоваться Gradle . Но при сборке пишет

```
15:06   Gradle sync failed: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение
```

Пошарился на StackOverflow и остальных, так и не понял в чем проблема.
Установлена последняя версия Intellij IDEA, Gradle.

Comment: это единственная выводимая строка?

Comment: @kami да.
Но уже неактуально. Пофиксил.